# coding length bound for coding of certain binary trees

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

the problem is this:

Consider all binary trees with roots where the vertices are not labeled and inner vertices have exactly 2 children. (See below for example trees with 3 and 5 vertices.)

Give a coding $f: \text{trees} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^*$ of the trees such that $ \mid f \mid \in O(n), $where $n$ ist the number of vertices of the tree; that is, the length of the coding is bounded by some linear function in $n$.

Attempted solution:

Consider the following coding:

$f(t)=a_1a_2...a_n$, where

$ a_i =$ $ \\ 
\begin{cases} 1, \text{if $v_i$ has 2 children} \\
0, \text{if $v_i$ has no children.} \end{cases} $

Here, $v_i$ is simply the ith vertex in the graph, counting normally from the upper left corner to the lower right corner. Here are examples:

[image: The one possible graph with 3 vertices and the two possible graphs with 5 vertices]

(Sorry for having really ugly graphs..)
The code for the first, second, and third graph are:
100, 11000 and 10100.

Appearently the size of the coding is $n$ in the case of $n$ vertices.

It seems more of less convincing to me, but I have a feeling as if something is missing here, isn't this too easy? Do I need to prove something else?

Thanks for any suggestions...

Comment: If the vertices are not labelled, how do you talk about the $v_i$th vertex? You can't count normally, because the drawing of the graph in the plane is additional information that you've made implicit in the representation. Your approach might still work, but there's something more to check or do. You've given an algorithm to produce the coding -- draw the graph and label and output the $a_i$ as described. Do you have an algorithm to reconstruct the tree (up to isomorphism) from the coding?

Comment: Are these plane binary trees, meaning that each vertex with children has a left child and a right child, or are the vertices not just not labelled, but also not oriented with respect to their parents?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! To be honest, I don't really know what they mean by 'unlabeled', I just tried to be close to our definition...but anyway, so I can't count here like this? Interesting..Yes I see that I sort of used the pictures to give a possibly not so precise idea about how to handle the situation...but wouldn't any representation of the graph (e,g, by a matrix) good enough to produce/compute the desired code? It seems to me that to get a unique tree from a coding is not a big deal, as far as I can see that is straightforward (if you read 1, give two children, if you read 0, go on..

Comment: Thanks for your comment, too. OK, yes let me see...yes each vertex that has two children has a left and right child (meaning I can distinguish them, I guess...), so they ARE oriented, I guess. As I say, in our definition of 'unlabeled' a few things are mentioned, I tried to make sense out of that and give a straight and simple formulation of the problem. Maybe I misunderstood something completely..